# How to get the Map view zoomlevel with solo abject in robotium for android implementing apk file only

Tags: android, robotium

I am working on robotium to test an android apk file.this apk file implementing robotium testcases .in mapview one button is inbuild buttons zoom in and zoom out buttons I would like to get the map view zoom level of certain stage. I don't know how to get with that by using solo in robotium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  solo.clickOnButton(0) its working fine in this function repeat multiple times